# ls command not working after killing process

Tags: shell-script, ls, gnu-screen, kill

I am very new to Linux, running an HPC via ssh. 
I was running a shell script within a screen, and a process was taking too long so I killed it via htop activity. When I reattach the screen that was running the script, it is unresponsive (attempt to control C just prints ^C on the screen).

Now, when I try to open the directory and use the ls command, the command does not complete after several minutes. I cannot access the shell script or any of the files using ls. The directory only has about 30 files are so. How can I fix this, or alternatively just remove the defective directory and screen?

UPDATE: was not able to move the files to a new directory using cp. I also see that there are a couple remnants of the processes viewable in htop activity, but I am unable to kill the process ID.

Comment: Have you tried logging into the HPC from a different terminal window? Does it work if you do that?

Comment: Yes I tried that but I am still unable to use -ls. Right now I am trying to transfer all the files from the directory to a new directory using cp but it is taking a very long time.

Comment: Ok. Why do you keep saying '-ls'? The command to list a directory contents is just 'ls [directory name]'.

Comment: sorry, I have edited the original post to fix that. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps your terminal was botched? Try `stty reset`

Comment: @JeffSchaller I reset both my local terminal and the HPC session with no luck :(

Comment: Was there several other processes running at the same time with heavy disk activity?

Comment: There were unkillable processes running put did not appear to be using memory according to htop activity. No other processes were running.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the HPC fixed the issue.

Comment: If by "HPC" you mean a multi-user compute cluster, then what did the other users think of your "solution"?

Comment: Apparently this had happened previously on the cluster, and some processes were existing in the background that would not be killed even by sigKILL. No other users were using it at the time, so we were able to reset it.